# Show Form Only to Specific User on Django

Tags: python, django

I have a blog part within my project. It's something simple. It has only title and content for now.. Basically, it looks like Facebook post form: on top of the post lists (you can easily visualise) and my problem comes here: with `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` code line I can allow my form to be seen only by the registered user. That's fine, but as a registered user when I visit other users' pages I can still see the form there. But, no! I want to show it (or I want it to be seen) only to the active user on its own page. So, I shouldn't see the form of other users when I visit their pages.

Shortly dear friends, my little post form must be visible only to an authenticated user on his/her own page, not to other users. How can I do it?

my codes:

My Model:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', verbose_name='Writer', related_name='posts')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Title')
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=240,verbose_name='Content')
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='PubDate', auto_now_add=True)
```

My View :

```
class AddPost(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_content'
                ]
    success_url = '/directory/dashboard'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(AddPost, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: What exactly makes a page yours?

Comment: what do you mean @schwobaseggl ?

Comment: There s nothing in your AddPost view that makes it a particular users. From the form valid, I take it, you only want the original author to edit their blog posts. That would rather be an issue in an UpdateView/DetailView, wouldnt it? Something like `{% if request.user == object.user and request.user.is_authenticated %}` should work anyway.

Comment: Yeah, as I didn't know how to write the best AddPost view which is set for a particular authenticated user I couldn't do it. But your code... it solved my problem. Thank you so much @schwobaseggl . Thanks a lot.